# ADB offline and missing issues

Tags: android, adb

I created an AWS EC2 instance, installed ADB on it. I then created an image of that AMI and launched 10 more AWS EC2s with it. The AMI made sure that the adbkey present in `~/.android/` location remains the same across all 10 instances. Now I assumed that if I trust one instance with a device all instances should automatically get trusted as all of them are using the same key. The theory works well, and all instances can connect to it. I have been though facing multiple flakiness in this approach

1. Often times, I see that when I execute `adb connect deviceIp` It says that connected but when I go to devices It shows `device offline`. I tried `adb kill-server && adb start-server` but no help. I tried restarting the device, no help. Furthermore, I used another instance and sometimes that connects and sometimes not. This led to me thinking that I should disconnect an instance after using it because maybe multiple instances cannot be connected to a device  at the same time. But that does not work either.
2. Another unique scenario, where after `adb connect deviceIp` when I execute `adb devices` it does not show, however it gave a confirmation about connected. For this, I tried toggling ADB debugging off and on, which sometimes work and sometimes not.

This is ok for ad hoc purposes, but I am trying to create a stable system to execute automation on multiple devices and hunting for something reliable. Am I missing something, otherwise ADB is turning out to be highly unreliable?

Comment: Does the same thing happen on a local machine or is it an EC2 only problem?

Comment: Try `adb pair ipaddr:port` first